# Python Process won't stop by calling kill method

Tags: python, tcp

So I'm trying having a self-made led-controller (raspberry pi).

The Controller should be able to play different scenes which were pre-defined by myself.
Now to the main problem...

The controller runs as TCP server and gets his scene-changes by tcp messages.
i coded a lot of scenes which need to run in an endless while loop.
So I decided to use multiprocessing to be able killing the running "scene process" if a new tcp message arrives.

So the awkward result of my two scripts are that if I'm running the server script on windows its perfectly working, but if im changing to run the server script on raspberry pi the running process isn't getting killed like it should.

so as my server test script I used the following:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

from time import sleep

try: 
    from analyse import *
    from handler import *
    from history import writeState
    from led import *
except: pass 

import socket


from subprocess import check_output #um die IP-Adresse unter Raspian auszulesen 
from platform import system


class SYSINFO():
    os=system() #Fragt das System nach dem laufenden OS-Typ ab

    if os=="Linux":
        IP_ADDRESS=check_output(["hostname",'-I']).decode().split(" ")[0]
    elif os=="Windows" or os=="Darwin":
        IP_ADDRESS=  socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())#"192.168.168.97"


class MyProcess(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, ):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.exit = multiprocessing.Event()

    def run(self):
        while not self.exit.is_set():
            print(round(time.perf_counter()), self.pid)
            time.sleep(1)
        print("You exited!")

    def shutdown(self):
        print("Shutdown initiated")
        self.exit.set()

class TCPController(multiprocessing.Process): 
    def __init__(self, ):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.exit = multiprocessing.Event()

    def run(self): 
        counter=0
        
    
    def shutdown(self):
        print("Shutdown initiated")
        self.exit.set()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    HOST = SYSINFO.IP_ADDRESS  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost
    PORT = 6060  # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)
    
    while True:

        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
            s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            s.bind((HOST, PORT))
            print(f"server listens under  {HOST!r} ,  {PORT!r} now")

            s.listen()
        
            while True: 
                try:
                    conn, addr = s.accept()
                    print("waiting for connection")
                    with conn: 
                        print(f"Connected by {addr}")
                        data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
                        print(data)
                        if data=="on": 
                            process = MyProcess()
                            process.daemon=True
                            process.start()
                            time.sleep(3)
                        elif data=="off": 
                            #process.shutdown()
                            process.kill()
                            time.sleep(3)
                            print("Child process state: %d" % process.is_alive())
                except: pass
                sleep(.5)
```

my client test cycle script looks like that

```
# echo-client.py

import socket

from time import sleep

class heimkinoSteuereinheit: 
        
    HOST = "192.168.168.97" #"192.168.168.97"  # The server's hostname or IP address
    PORT = 6060  # The port used by the server


def cinemaclient(msg):

    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((heimkinoSteuereinheit.HOST, heimkinoSteuereinheit.PORT))
        s.sendall(msg.encode())
        data = s.recv(1024).decode()
       
    print(f"Received {data!r}")
    return data

while True: 
  sleep(1)
  cinemaclient("on")
  sleep(5)
  cinemaclient("off")
```

Hope you guys could help.

Thanks for your help,
Luca

Answer (score 0):

The variable process is only defined in the

```
if data=="on"
```

While you use the variable process in the

```
if data=="off
```

It has not been defined. Is that done intentionally?

Furthermore what do you mean by the code isn't working. Do you get any errors?

Comment: The scripts are basically working on both machines. I’m toggeling the „on“ „off“ procedure by sending tcp messages via the client.py script.

What I meant with „isn’t working“ is that if I’m running the server.py script on the raspberry machine it’s not killing the process in case: If data==„off““

Meanwhile If I’m running the server script on windows it’s working like it should and the process is successfully getting killed.

Are there maybe some architecture differences between the process handling on windows vs raspian machines ?